# Howto configure LWPx::ParanoidAgent to use /etc/hosts

Tags: perl, dns, hosts, lwp, lwp-useragent

Recently I switch from using LWP::UserAgent to LWPx::ParanoidAgent to fetch URLs provided by 3rd parties.

Its all very well, except sometimes a lookup in /etc/hosts is needed to resolve a domain. LWP::UserAgent did that automatically, but LWPx::ParanoidAgent only queries real DNS servers.

How can I configure LWPx::ParanoidAgent to search /etc/hosts, too ?

Update:
The module lets me set a DNS resolver (Net::DNS::Resolver). Is there a way to have a DNS resolver that looks into /etc/hosts, too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the module's source. It can't be configured to do so.

By the way, it's not using the normal name resolution system since it wants to know if the host resolves to another host name (i.e. when it's a CNAME) so it can check that host name against the host black and white lists too.

If you wanted to add this functionality, I suggest wrapping `LWPx::ParanoidAgent::_resolve` with something that checks `/etc/hosts` directly (when `!$depth`) before falling back to the original `_resolve`. Providing a Net::DNS::Resolver look-alike would be significantly more work.

Comment: It seems you can set a DNS resolver. I was hoping there is a clever way to set a DNS resolver that looks into /etc/hosts, too.

Comment: Yes, you can write your own resolver that presents the same interface as Net::DNS::Resolver. It would actually be easier to wrap `_resolve` with something that checks `/etc/hosts` directly before falling back to the original `_resolve`.